# sample open src SIMPLE j2ee skeleton application

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts

I have worked on java/jsp project at university leve.I have develped apps in java,jsp , servlet and hibernate.But i think my coding style is not up to level.Means it is not properly modularized .
I have seen many opens src CMS and other ope srcs apps code but they are too complecated to understand.
I want to see the code of a open src skelton j2ee apps and then want to implemet my own.
I want to incorpaorate plug  and play feature in my app.
Meaning if i devlop a admin odule now , i shold  be able to add other modules later in it without affecting the othere partt of the applicactiton.

Can any one suggest me a good skeleton app.

I want to use following tecnologies . java,jsp,servlet,struts and hibernate

Answer (score 0):

The Java EE 6 homepage has several samples: [Java EE 6 Sample Applications](http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/code/). Further there's the [Appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) which gives you the possibility to compose a kickoff Java EE application together yourself based on a certain MVC framework ([JSF](http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net), [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/index.html), etc) and plug in several modules sooner or later like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org) and so on.